# Spark to read BlobStorage files "java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, apache-spark-xml

Currently, I'm using the azure-storage-blob and hadoop-azure packages for downloading files from a Blob Storage to local.

```
...
String url = "https://blob_storage_url";

String filename = url.replaceFirst("https.*/", "");

// Setup the cloud storage account
String storageConnectionString = "...";
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

// Create a blob service client
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

// Get a reference to a container
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);

for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs(filename)) {
    // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory
    if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
        // Download the file
        CloudBlockBlob retrievedBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobItem;
        retrievedBlob.downloadToFile(filename);
    }
}
...
```

These downloaded files are really XML files. Then, I've to process the content for each one. To do this, I use spark-xml_2.11 (com.databricks.spark.xml) package.

```
StructType schema = new StructType()
    .add("attr1", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    .add("attr2", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
    ... other_structFields_or_structTypes;

Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .schema(schema)
    .load(filename)
```

The load() method requires a path (data backed by a local or distributed file system). So, is there an option to load them from Blob Storage directly?

I found this guide https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html But the first option, Mount Azure Blob Storage containers to DBFS, requires a Databrick cluster.

With the second option, Access Azure Blob Storage directly, I tested setting up the account access key before.

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<my-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<my-storage-account-access-key>"
);

StructType schema = new StructType()
    .add("attr1", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    .add("attr2", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
    ... other_structFields_or_structTypes;

Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .schema(schema)
    .load(filename) # also I tried with the full url
```

But the following exception was raised:

```
"java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https".
```

Also, I tried to change the protocol to wasbs, but again a similar exception was raised:

```
"java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs".
```

Please, any suggestion or comment?

Comment: add dependecy jar to access azure blob filesystem

Comment: Project is managed with maven and all dependencies are included/imported.

Comment: so from where  are you accessing your blob storage like local or somewhere else

Comment: @MaheshGupta from local

Comment: so you need to replace all jar(spark_home/jars) with newly generated jar by Maven and then try to run

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you, or maybe I explained it wrong before.None Spark installation/deployment exists on my computer. It's a Java project with all maven dependencies (spark, azure, hadoop...) included in pom.xml. So, I run it locally. The spark job starts/runs locally, accesses to blob storage, gets the files and finally reads their content (XML).